# FormatConditions Formula1 compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add Conditional Format using three formula conditions. But I got Compile error message. Please help me fix this error.

```
With Range("Y2:Z100000").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_
Formula1:="=AND($X2="",$Y2<>$Z2, $AM2="N")"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double the quotes inside the formula string in VBA

```
With Range("Y2:Z100000").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_
Formula1:="=AND($X2="""",$Y2<>$Z2, $AM2=""N"")")
```

Comment: Think just a closing bracket had gone astray - added above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I modified the syntax according to your advice. With Range("Y2:Z100000")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($X2="""",$Y2<>$Z2,$AM2=""N"")"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 102)
    End With